# How to differentiate between Adobe Acrobat Standard vs Professional in SCCM

Tags: sql, windows, sccm

i'm currently in the middle of a software license review for my organization, and I am attempting to document how many instances of paid software we have installed on end-user machines.

For the example I used in the title (with Adobe Acrobat Standard vs Professional) where there doesn't seem to be any difference in the installation folder/exe, how would you suggest demarcating this within SCCM to pull the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of these two products you use because on our systems they have quite different installation paths (%ProgramFiles%\adobe reader vs acrobat) as well as file names (AcroRd32.exe vs Acrobat.exe).

However another method to differentiate would be the "File Description" of the executable. This or the "Product Name" should be different in any case. This is something you would see in any file inventory.

Another approach would be to rely on the data the sccm gathers regarding the entry of a software in the Add/Remove programs section of the computer. This is basically a registry entry in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and will most probably also show a different name for those softwares.

As you included the SQL tag in the questions I assume you want to query the database for this info. In that case a view for basic file info would be:
v_GS_SoftwareFile one for the Add/Remove Programs would be v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS for example.